# Checking a value inside a string

Tags: regex, swift

This shouldn't be so hard...

I want to check the values of a label that is dependent of a UIDatePicker and return an alert message if the user is under age. Everything works, except there is a mistake somewhere in the definition of the constraint.

the string that is being read is in a Long Date format, such as "November 18, 1965"

It works 'sometimes' for some years even between 2010 and 2015, some times it doesn't work at all. I've tried changing the second bracket to [0-9] and it says the user is underage for any year, meaning there is something wrong with the syntax or I am perhaps missing something? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
func isValidBirthday(testStr4:String) -> Bool {
        println("validate birthday: \(testStr4)")

        let birthdayRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z ]+[, ]+[1900-2010]"

        if let birthdayTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", birthdayRegEx) {
            return birthdayTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr4)
        }

        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with your regex. You can't just match numbers in the range 1900-2010 the way you're trying to. Instead, try

```
let birthdayRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z ]+[, ]+(19[0-9][0-9]|200[0-9]|2010)"
```

However, it seems like a much more natural way to do this is by converting the string to an NSDate. You can use code like

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
let birthday = dateFormatter.dateFromString(testStr4)
```

and then compare testStr4 to the current date with `timeIntervalSinceDate`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot. That sounds like it should fix the problem :)